# Страница открывается 3-4 секунды django

Tags: python, django

Замер выполнения времени кода, но страница открывается **3-4 секунды**:

*--- 0.11155128479003906 seconds ---*

**views**

```
class OrdersHomeView(RelatedMixin, ListView):
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'orders/orders_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'orders'
    related_module_name = 'orders'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Orders.objects.all()
        orders = self.getCleanQuery(queryset=queryset, request=self.request) #0.2 sec
        return orders

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        dict_orders = self.get_queryset()
        paginator = Paginator(dict_orders, self.paginate_by)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            orders_page = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            page = 1
            orders_page = paginator.page(page)
        except EmptyPage:
            orders_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['related_list'] = self.getDataListRelated(query=orders_page)
        print(" --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        return context
```

ps: другие views, где нет обращений к базе открываются сразу.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что все операции с QuerySet-ами в Django только лишь составляют SQL-запрос. Сам запрос начнёт выполняться только при доступе к этим данным (возможно, уже во время рендеринга на страницы), поэтому замеры времени выплнения в коде view неинформативны.

Comment: @VladislavPavkin так и есть. а что делать? получается надо вызвать запрос для пагинатора, прежде чем начнется рендер?

Comment: А похоже, у вас так и сделано: orders_page = paginator.page(page). У меня нет решения, глядя на этот код. Но я бы предложил попробовать Django Debug Toolbar. Он наглядно покажет на что вьюха тратит время, какие запросы выполняет и сколько каждый из них длится.